# How to remove all records from collection after browser refresh?

Tags: meteor, database, nosql

I need to remove all records from selected collection in mongo while session ends (for example after browser refresh).
So let's say I want to save tasks in collection, but when session ends I want to have clear table and no records should be inside collection.

Is there any possibiliy to do such a thing? If there is better way to achieve the same result, please let me know.

Comment: Why did you put the tasks in a mongo collection if you want to delete it after a refresh ?

Comment: `Template.myTemplateName.destroyed`[link](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onDestroyed) is where your code to remove the data from collection , etc should go.

Comment: Im trying to do:
Template.myTemplate.onDestroyed(function() { Meteor.call('func_which_removes_collection') });
but this doesnt work.

Comment: Did you use Angularjs or React ?

Comment: Nothing of above, I am just using Meteor stack.

Answer (score 0):

Please include your inserting function in destroy meteod after re-rendering data will be destroy

```
  Template.templatename.onDestroyed(function () {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Template.templateName.onDestroyed(function(){
    Meteor.call('removeAll')
});
```

Your method:

```
removeAll: function (){
   CollectionName.remove({},{multi: true})
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work neither. I was trying to do such a thing before, but after page refresh all records are still in collection.

Comment: can you edit your question and include all your related codes then? we can't possibly know whats wrong without seeing your codes.